# Can I cast event args inside the called function in C# instead of defining delegates?

Tags: c#, events, methods, casting, delegates

I have an event:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler ActionEvent;
```

I have a superclass:

```
internal class MyEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public enum SomeAction
    {
        ACTION1,
        ACTION2,
        ACTION3
    }

    public MyEvent(SomeAction action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public SomeAction action;
}
```

I call the function:

```
private void onAction(object sender, MyEventArgs args) { if (ActionEvent != null) ActionEvent(sender, args); }
```

And finally, hence my question, I cast inside the called method:

```
void ActionEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyEvent args = (MyEvent)e;
}
```

Is this legal? Can I avoid introducing delegates? It compiles and runs happily in debug mode.

(I'm new in C#. I have been using C++ for ages. The answer would be a definite yes in C++, but I want to double check that I can do this in C# as well without introducing "hidden" stability problems, multi-threading problems or anything like that. In fact, C# should warn me in real-time if I used a wrong cast, but just I asked just to double check.)

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this, even if you could?  If you want the event to use `MyEventArgs` then define the event to pass in that type, rather than a supertype that you just expect the handlers to cast it to.

Comment: It looks like MyEvent is supposed to read MyEventArgs in the above code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this - but then you're really being very specific in your implementation, without being specific in the type system.

Why not just use [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ActionEvent;
```

Then:

```
void ActionEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```